# The user is logged in vs The user is logged-in

Tags: adjectives, phrasal-verbs, participles

> 1. The user is logged in.
> 2. The user is logged-in.

Are both of these sentences correct? In the first sentence, is `logged in` a participial adjective? If it's not, what is it called and how is it related to the verb `is`?

Thanks!

Comment: The second one is incorrect.  We only use the hyphenated form before a noun, like "the logged-in user".

Comment: Thanks, in the first sentence, is `logged in` still an adjective?

Answer (score 4):

As stangdon says, the hyphenated form is an adjective usually placed before the noun:

> **Logged-in** users have privileges based on their assigned role.

Otherwise, as in your first sentence, don't hyphenate:

> When users are first **logged in**, they are assigned a specific role.

Comment: Thanks, in the first sentence that I wrote, is `logged in` still an adjective?

Comment: @user1764381  it would probably be classified as a [*participle*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm) that acts like an adjective, similar to *"the bread **is toasted**"*